# How to diagnose and fix a key-binding conflict in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

My default [key-bindings](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html) for pasting are

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+v"], "command": "paste" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+v"], "command": "paste_and_indent" },
```

I overrode them in my user key-bindings with

```
{ "keys": ["alt+k"], "command": "paste" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+k"], "command": "paste_and_indent" },
```

I use [Dvorak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_Simplified_Keyboard) keyboard, which means *your* <kbd>V</kbd> is *my* <kbd>K</kbd>. Also, I want `paste_and_indent` to be the default.

But <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> executes `paste`, not `paste_and_indent`. I determined this by turning on command logging in the console, with

```
sublime.log_commands(True)
```

However, if I make the `paste_and_indent` command to something else, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, it correctly calls `paste_and_indent`.

I looked through the key-bindings for all of my installed packages, and don't see any other command using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>. I also disabled most of my packages except syntaxes. I even accidentally [disabled Package Control](https://superuser.com/questions/489075/re-enable-package-control-in-sublime-text-2), but still, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> only executes `paste`.

How can I determine and fix this conflict, so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> executes `paste_and_indent`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out the [`FindKeyConflicts`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/FindKeyConflicts) plugin. There are several options for looking at all key bindings, or just conflicting ones, in a variety of contexts. All the options are available via the Command Palette.

Comment: Turns out I had a conflict with a redundant User keymap file. I thought it was okay to move my keymap file from the User root directory `C:\Users\jeffy\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\Default (Windows).sublime-keymap` to a `keymap` sub-directory, but it's not. Great utility.

Comment: @aliteralmind glad I could help. Yes, Sublime searches through **every** subdirectory looking for `.sublime-settings`, `.tmTheme`, `.tmLanguage`, `.sublime-keymap`, etc. files, so if you want to make a backup or something you need to move it out of the `Packages` hierarchy.

Comment: Right. You can't move these files because, it seems, the "Key Bindings" items (and the "settings", too) in the Preferences menu are hard-coded to the User's root directory. Attempting to move them (to a `keymap` directory, for example) actually results in a duplicate. It's a shame, because these files clutter up my User directory. Snippets and autocompletes can indeed be moved to sub-directories. Thanks again.