# In Sublime Text, can I generate a list of the effective settings?

Tags: sublimetext

In Sublime Text, I'm sometimes wasting time hunting down why a particular keyboard binding isn't working or what's the effective or final value for a specific setting. How do I see what Sublime Text has calculated for each setting? Can I get a list of all calculated settings and/or keybindings?

I've tried searching for "effective settings", "calculated settings", "final settings", and I'm finding nothing. Maybe I'm just using the wrong words?

For now, I've just made rather large user settings and user keybinding files that we're all sharing. That's good enough for now, but I'd like an extra tool in my arsenal for troubleshooting inconsistent settings, especially effective keybindings which vary significantly depending on what extensions are installed. We're not all working on the same projects, so we don't all have identical environments, and unfortunately, these user preference files seem to override project preferences, which I wish had higher priority.

Am I just going about this the wrong way? Please enlighten me.

Comment: After receiving @Peh's answer below, which is right on, I started searching for "sublime text key conflicts" and various similar terms. http://stackoverflow.com/q/26123859/1298086 and http://superuser.com/q/621541 answer that same question about determining keybinding conflicts, although the common answer, [FindKeyConflicts](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FindKeyConflicts) does not tell you what the effective/final key binding is for a given scope or context. The remainder of the question, which asks to determine effective/calculated/final settings, still stands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least for key mapping conflicts there is a plugin called [FindKeyConflicts](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FindKeyConflicts). The command `FindKeyConflicts: All Key Maps To Buffer` shows a list of all key bindings and there are several commands to check which keys conflicts.

Comment: Ok. This is nice. Thank you for this reference. As a bonus, the readme for FindKeyConflicts also mentions the `sublime.log_commands(True)` statement, which can be run in the the Sublime Text Console (`ctrl-\``) and may be a reasonable quickie tool for troubleshooting.

Comment: At the time I asked this question, I didn't realize how likely it would be to require 2 answers, one for keymaps and one for settings. So, for now, I'll let the question sit and fester a bit. If a second answer appears, I'll pick one or the other as the "accepted" answer.