# Sublime Text 3 doesn't allow me to type ">" when I'm writing some JS

Tags: javascript, keyboard, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I love Sublime Text, it's my favorite code editor, but, sometimes inexplicable things happen (and that's not very often). My problem here is that I can't type the `>` symbol when I'm writing JavaScript. When I try to type `>`, it shows me an alert:

> Could not find a definition

That's very annoying, especially when I want to write modern JavaScript, for example, when I write a function like this:

```
const myFunction = () => {
    console.log("Hello world!);
}
```

I'm running Sublime Text 3 (stable channel) Build 3126 on OS X El Capitan. Is there a way to change the keybinding or something similar?

**Edit:** I'm using a French Canadian Keyboard, it mean that I have to hold `alt` before typing `>`

Comment: I'm not sure if it works, but have a look here: [http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/key-bindings](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/key-bindings) . Maybe you can find the right key binding .. I can't test it, as I do not use a Mac

Comment: Is there a problem with your keyboard? Never able to press `>` or only rarely?

Comment: @DanStef Ok, so I checked and I have no `Default.sublime-keymap` how would I proceed to create the "Default" one? Even if you don't have a mac

Comment: @sabithpocker no, it doesn't come from the keyboard

Comment: Sublime is missing ES6 syntax support out of the box I believe. Might want to install some extentions to support the syntax. Might work

Comment: @MathijsRutgers I installed Babel, but it's the same, doesn't work

Comment: Can you go to the keyboard shortcuts and paste it here? Also a screenshot of the alert might help.

Comment: @sabithpocker a screenshot won't help, I already provided the entire alert, there is only "Could not find a definition" when I type ">"

Comment: Can you post the keyboard shortcuts list?

Comment: @sabithpocker As I said, I have no shortcuts list

Comment: It will be there in Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Key Bindings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to diagnose and fix key-binding conflict in Sublime Text 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26123859/how-to-diagnose-and-fix-key-binding-conflict-in-sublime-text-3)

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem can be solved by:
1- look if your preferences are correct, here there is a link with help:
[Sublime Preferences](https://www.granneman.com/webdev/editors/sublime-text/configuring-sublime-text/)
2- by using Atom.. (even looks the same, and have a huge community behind it)

Comment: I don't want to use Atom, my Mac is very old and I already tried Atom, but because it's a web that uses the web to render everything, it's a bit laggy